How to save a list of data in txt format in mathematica?
I have the following program in mathematica
    Do[a = E^(-1.5*t^2);
      numcam = 3;
      matriz[numcam_] := a^(ToeplitzMatrix[numcam] - 1);
      A = matriz[numcam];
      MatrizDiagonal = 
       Block[{Y = A, X, D}, {X, D} = JordanDecomposition[Y];
        Table /@ {D}];
      Print[t, Eigenvalues[MatrizDiagonal]], {t, 0, 1, 0.1}];

which prints the data below on the screen
0.{3.,1.77636*10^-15,0.}
0.1{2.96046,0.0295545,0.00998306}
0.2{2.8472,0.11308,0.039716}
0.3{2.67492,0.236621,0.0884589}
0.4{2.46407,0.381217,0.15471}
0.5{2.23644,0.527633,0.235925}
0.6{2.01124,0.660404,0.328357}
0.7{1.80276,0.770075,0.427164}
0.8{1.61973,0.853393,0.526872}
0.9{1.46593,0.911963,0.622105}
1.{1.34143,0.950213,0.708359}

I want to save this data in the form of a table (txt file format) where the number of columns can vary according to the "numcam" variable that is declared in the program, i.e., if numcam = 2 we have three columns  t A B, or if numcam = 3 we have four columns t A B C, or if numcam = 4 we have five columns t A B C D.
How can I do this?


Can you use https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Write.html to do what you want?

Your code is very non-idiomatic. Here is an equivalent rewrite:
numcam = 3;
a = E^(-1.5*t^2);
A = a^(ToeplitzMatrix[numcam] - 1);
MatrizDiagonal = Last@JordanDecomposition[A];
evals = Eigenvalues@MatrizDiagonal;

results = Table[Flatten@{t, evals}, {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]

Export["path/to/yourFile.txt", results, "TSV"]


Thank you, but the code written this way will take a long time to generate the data because I will do the study for the numcam variable above 10. That's why I had done it the other way.
